# Timer case contains x in y

Tags: vb.net

my verification doesn't work at all.

TxtLstofDraws.Lines(i) = the index starts at 1, so the first one is always empty.

```
1,2
3,4
17,29
47,44
```

and so on...

and TxtBoxIntDrawsY contains like: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20` which means a  of 20. all time (20 items)

When a variant of txtlstofdraws exists in txtboxintdrawsy, then it should do what I give it, the problem is that it doesn't do what I give it, and it goes on to true cases, regardless of whether that x exists in y.

so where is the problem? do I have to change the code to work? I really don't know why it works

```
Private Sub AnyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick, Timer2.Tick, Timer3.Tick, Timer4.Tick, Timer5.Tick, Timer6.Tick, Timer7.Tick, Timer8.Tick, Timer9.Tick, Timer10.Tick
        Dim t As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer)
        Dim strx As String
        Dim stry As String
        stry = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text
        For i As Integer = 1 To 11
            strx = TxtLstofDraws.Lines(i)
            If stry.Contains(strx) = True Then
                TxtRndValLines.Text = ("0")
                TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("1")
                TxtLstofCase.Text = ("1")
                BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                Exit For
            Else
                Dim TextBox4Contents As String = ""
                Select Case True
                    Case t Is Timer1
                        TextBox4Contents = "1"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("0")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("1")
                    Case t Is Timer2
                        TextBox4Contents = "2"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("1")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("2")
                    Case t Is Timer3
                        TextBox4Contents = "3"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("2")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("3")
                    Case t Is Timer4
                        TextBox4Contents = "4"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("3")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("4")
                    Case t Is Timer5
                        TextBox4Contents = "5"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("4")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("5")
                    Case t Is Timer6
                        TextBox4Contents = "6"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("5")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("6")
                    Case t Is Timer7
                        TextBox4Contents = "7"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("6")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("7")
                    Case t Is Timer8
                        TextBox4Contents = "8"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("7")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("8")
                    Case t Is Timer9
                        TextBox4Contents = "9"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("8")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("9")
                    Case t Is Timer10
                        TextBox4Contents = "10"
                        TxtRndValLines.Text = ("9")
                        TxtRndValLinesy.Text = ("10")
                End Select
                If TxtLstofBf.Text = TextBox4Contents Then
                    BttRndAuto.PerformClick()
                Else
                    Select Case True
                        Case t Is Timer1
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("1")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer2
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("2")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer3
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("3")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer4
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("4")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer5
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("5")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer6
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("6")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer7
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("7")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer8
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("8")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer9
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("9")
                            BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                        Case t Is Timer10
                            TxtLstofCase.Text = ("1")
                            BttRndAuto.PerformClick()
                        Case Else
                            Return
                    End Select
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        t.Stop()
        t.Enabled = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Button.

```
Private Sub BttRndBF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttRndBF.Click
      If TxtLstofCase.Text = ("1") Then
                Timer2.Enabled = True
                Timer2.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("2") Then
                Timer3.Enabled = True
                Timer3.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("3") Then
                Timer4.Enabled = True
                Timer4.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("4") Then
                Timer5.Enabled = True
                Timer5.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("5") Then
                Timer6.Enabled = True
                Timer6.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("6") Then
                Timer7.Enabled = True
                Timer7.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("7") Then
                Timer8.Enabled = True
                Timer8.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("8") Then
                Timer9.Enabled = True
                Timer9.Start()
            ElseIf TxtLstofCase.Text = ("9") Then
                Timer10.Enabled = True
                Timer10.Start()
            End If
```

Comment: Debug your code.  That's why VS has a debugger.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step.  You can then see exactly how your code behaves and exactly how that behaviour differs from your expectations.  Even if you can't work out a solution, at least you can be far more specific about the problem. You should also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems unlikely that you need all that code to demonstrate the problem, which means that you haven't tried to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is look at the code and see where things are being repeated. Work out how you can eliminate `If`s or `Case`s and turn them into calculations. Remember that computers are really good at calculations as long as you tell them the right thing to calculate.

To do that, you may need to convert something like Timer1, Timer2,... Timer10 into a List(Of Timer) so that it can be indexed with a number. (In the same way as an array, but it is usually more convenient to use a List because it changes its size as required.) Numbers are good for calculations, names of variables are not.

Once that is done, you can see if the code still makes sense now that it is simpler. If not, you will need to correct the logic.

Given only what I can see in the question, I came up with this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim timers As List(Of Timer)

    Private Sub AnyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim tim = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer)
        Dim timerNum = CInt(tim.Tag)

        Dim y As String = TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text

        For i As Integer = 1 To TxtLstofDraws.Lines.Count() - 1
            Dim x = TxtLstofDraws.Lines(i)

            If y.Contains(x) Then
                TxtRndValLines.Text = "0"
                TxtRndValLinesy.Text = "1"
                TxtLstofCase.Text = "1"
                BttRndBF.PerformClick()
                Exit For

            Else
                Dim textBox4Contents As String = timerNum.ToString()
                TxtRndValLines.Text = (timerNum - 1).ToString()
                TxtRndValLinesy.Text = timerNum.ToString()

                If TxtLstofBf.Text = textBox4Contents Then
                    BttRndAuto.PerformClick()
                Else
                    If timerNum >= 1 AndAlso timerNum <= 10 Then
                        TxtLstofCase.Text = timerNum.ToString()
                    Else
                        Return
                    End If

                End If

                Exit For

            End If

        Next

        tim.Stop()
        tim.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub BttRndBF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttRndBF.Click
        Dim x = 0
        If Integer.TryParse(TxtLstofCase.Text, x) Then
            If x >= 0 AndAlso x < timers.Count() Then
                timers(x + 1).Enabled = True
                timers(x + 1).Start()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub SetUpTimers()
        timers = New List(Of Timer)
        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim tim As New Timer() With {.Enabled = False, .Interval = 1000, .Tag = i}
            AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf AnyTimer_Tick
            timers.Add(tim)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TxtLstofDraws.Text = "
1,2
3,4
17,29
47,44"

        TxtBoxIntDrawsY.Text = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 20))

        SetUpTimers()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' Cleanup
        If timers IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each tim In timers
                tim.Stop()
                RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf AnyTimer_Tick
                tim.Dispose()
            Next
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

For the above code, note that a Timer has a [Tag property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tag?view=netframework-4.8) which is an Object, and you can use that to store whatever you like, such an identifying number.

So the problem of finding where the problem is should now be solved.